# Write powershell script analyze log

Tags: parsing, search, powershell, logging

I am very new to Powershell, and I need some kind of Powershell script. Log files are in D:\Example\Example\log\ folder. It is created day by day like log20140513.log.

I just want to check the logfile's last 1 hour data searching "Runstate is false!" and if it find, it should return 1, else return 0. That's it.

Here is what I have:

```
$file = "D:\EnterAccount\Gecko\log\log20140513.log" 
cat $file | Select-String "ERROR" -SimpleMatch | select -expand line | foreach {
    $_ -match '(.+)\s[ERROR]\s\.\s(.+)' | out-null 
    new-object psobject -Property @{
        Timestamp = [datetime]$matches[1];Error = $matches[2]
    } | where {$_.timestamp -gt (get-date).AddDays(-1)
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is here to help people to program, you can't ask users to do your work, you doesnt show any research/ programming effort.

Comment: I understand that, sorry. But i tried and it doesn't help

Comment: I tried this, but it check just one named log.
$file = "D:\EnterAccount\Gecko\log\log20140513.log" 
cat $file |
 Select-String "ERROR" -SimpleMatch |
  select -expand line |
   foreach {
              $_ -match '(.+)\s\[ERROR\]\s\.\s(.+)' | out-null
              new-object psobject -Property @{Timestamp = [datetime]$matches[1];Error = $matches[2]} |
              where {$_.timestamp -gt (get-date).AddDays(-1)}
            }

Comment: Do you want only things logged after 11:00PM or only things logged in the last hour of the file? i.e. the last thing logged was at 9:43PM because the service crashed, you want things 8:43PM-9:43PM

Comment: Since no problem was explicitly stated in this question, I am voting to put on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create an array of all your log files then run your code upon each ones :

```
$files = get-childitem D:\EnterAccount\Gecko\log\ -filter *.log | ?{ $_.lastwritetime -gt ((get-date).addHours(-1)) }
$files | foreach{
    cat $_ | Select-String "ERROR" -SimpleMatch | select -expand line | foreach {
        $_ -match '(.+)\s[ERROR]\s\.\s(.+)' | out-null 
        new-object psobject -Property @{
            Timestamp = [datetime]$matches[1];Error = $matches[2]
        } | where {$_.timestamp -gt (get-date).AddDays(-1)
    }
}
```